# Angular: just the last value of the array appears in html table iteration

Tags: angular

I passed input data from "create" component via service to the "check" component. I store these input data in an array('receipts[]') in the "check" component. When ngFor iterate over them in a table of the check html file ,there shows JUST the last value of my array. I logged my array to the console and all my data are in... What can be the problem?

Please could you give me any advice?

(My whole project: https://github.com/suvegesrebeka/szamlakezelo)
Thanks!

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hwald4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Freceiptdata.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fcreate%2Fcreate.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fcreate%2Fcreate.component.html

The check ts file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("check oninit");

    this.subscription();
}

  receipts:any[]=[];

  subscription() {
    this.receiptdataService.behaveiorSubject$.subscribe((res:any)=>{
      for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(res)) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${val} + 2. respo`);
      }
      this.receipts.push(res)
      console.log(this.receipts)
    })
  }
```

The check html file:

```
<h2 class="display-6">Kiállított számlák:</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Vásárló neve</th>
        <th>Kiállítás dátuma</th>
        <th>Esedékesség dátuma</th>
        <th>Tétel neve</th>
        <th>Komment</th>
        <th>Ár</th>
   <tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of receipts" >
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td >{{item.date}}</td>
        <td >{{item.date2}}</td>
        <td >{{item.item}}</td>
        <td >{{item.comment}}</td>
        <td >{{item.price}}</td>
    </tr>
  
</table>
```

service:

```
  private sourceBehav = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public behaveiorSubject$ = this.sourceBehav.asObservable();
  
  showReceipt(value: any) {
    this.sourceBehav.next(value)
  }
```

The create component ts: (data go from here)

```
  sendData(value: any): void {
    // for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(value)) {
    //   console.log(`${key}: ${val}`);
    // }
    this.receiptdataService.showReceipt(value);
  }
```

create's html:

```
<div>
  <h2 class="display-6">Állítson elő számlát:</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="receiptform" #save="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(save.value)" action="POST">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="cusName" class="form-label">Vásárló neve</label>
        <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="cusName" #nameval>
      </li>
      <span *ngIf=" name!.invalid && (name!.dirty || name!.touched)">
        <span [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}" *ngIf="name!.errors?.['required']">
          A név kötelező!
        </span>
        <span [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}" *ngIf="name!.errors?.['pattern']">
          Hibás formmátum!
        </span>
      </span>
      <li>
        <label for="date" class="form-label">Kiállítás dátuma</label>
        <input formControlName="date" [max]="maxDate" type="date" class="form-control" id="date">
      </li>
      <span *ngIf=" date!.invalid && (date!.dirty || date!.touched)">
        <span [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}" *ngIf="date!.errors?.['required']">
          A dátum kötelező!
        </span>
      </span>
      <li>
        <label for="date" class="form-label">Esedékesség dátuma</label>
        <input formControlName="date2" type="date" class="form-control" id="date">
      </li>
      <span *ngIf=" date2!.invalid && (date2!.dirty || date2!.touched)">
        <span [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}" *ngIf="date2!.errors?.['required']">
          A dátum kötelező!
        </span>
      </span>
      <li>
        <label for="item" class="form-label">Tétel neve</label>
        <input formControlName="item" type="text" class="form-control" id="item">
      </li>
      <span *ngIf=" item!.invalid && (item!.dirty || item!.touched)">
        <span [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}" *ngIf="item!.errors?.['required']">
          A tétel kötelező!
        </span>
      </span>
      <li>
        <label for="comment">Komment</label>
        <textarea formControlName="comment" class="form-control" id="comment"></textarea>
      </li>
      <span *ngIf=" comment!.invalid && (comment!.dirty || comment!.touched)">
        <span [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}" *ngIf="comment!.errors?.['required']">
          Kötelező kommentelni!
        </span>
      </span>
      <li>
        <label for="price">Ár</label>
        <span style="width:30%" class="input-group mb-3">
          <input formControlName="price" type="number" min=1 class="form-control" id="price">
          <span class="input-group-text">,-Ft</span>
        </span>
      </li>
      <span *ngIf=" price!.invalid && (price!.dirty || price!.touched)">
        <span [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}" *ngIf="price!.errors?.['required']">
          Az árkötelező!
        </span>

      </span>
      <button (click)="sendData(save.value)" [disabled]="!receiptform.valid" type="submit"
        class=" btn btn-outline-success">Mentés</button>
      <button routerLink="../subscription" class="mx-3 btn btn-outline-secondary">Visszalépés</button>

    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a stackblitz, would be great for debugging the recurring issue!

Comment: Please share the data that's being returned from `behaveiorSubject$`.

Comment: Try `this.receipts = [...this.receipts, res]` instead of `this.receipts.push(res)`

Comment: @NarenMurali i added the link below the text and

Comment: @PhilippMeissner i uptated !

Comment: Unfortunatelly it 's not working. @marcel

Comment: your stackblitz doesn't compile and functions are missing like `ReceiptdataService.getData()`

Comment: In this call `this.receiptdataService.showReceipt(value);` `value` is an array?

Comment: @derstauner no, it' get a object with all of the input values. And when i click the 'mentés' button it send the formvalue to the service and to the check component.But when i click multiply times to the button appears alway just the last object i sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of all you issues is the below line of code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css'],
  providers: [], // <- problem here
})

export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {
```

never add providers in the component, if you intend to share the service with adjacent components, either let it have `providedIn` or add to providers of app module.

Another mistake is in the HTML you are not creating table cells for each of the rows, the html table should be restructured as follows!

```
<h2 class="display-6">Kiállított számlák:</h2>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Vásárló neve</th>
    <th>Kiállítás dátuma</th>
    <th>Esedékesség dátuma</th>
    <th>Tétel neve</th>
    <th>Komment</th>
    <th>Ár</th>
  </tr>

  <tr></tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of receiptObservable$ | async"> <!-- mistake here -->
    <td>{{ item.cusName }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.buyDate }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.realDate }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.product }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.cusComment }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.prodPrice }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.prodPrice }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button routerLink="../create" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
  Új számla kiállítása
</button>
```

> I am intializing a behaviour subject which stores the array and updates if a new row is pushed! and on the other component I subscribe for changes also I am using `async` pipe which eliminates the need for subscribing to get the array data, another advantage is that it auto unsubscribes from the observable!

I have done a lot of rework and it basically works, do try to tweak it, let me know if any doubts!

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1p4n1d)

Comment: I think it a little bit differently. Every time she registers a new invoice, this invoice will be passed to the create component, but if we click to see the list (the create component), the component will be created with an empty `receipts` array every time, and the invoice gets added to this. And that's why she sees only the last invoice. Now, an array is passed in the service to the component with the new invoice, it will show all the invoices. Of course, all other statements are right.

Comment: @derstauner I updated my answer as to why she is seeing only one row, I think its due the ngFor now looped over `tr` instead it was done on `td`

Comment: Thank you ,i appreciate your time and work in this project! I understood the problem and fixed. Your solution is perfect! @NarenMurali